# How to Access Entry TextBox value in Xamarin Forms within a Content Template

Tags: .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin Form XAML that I would like to reset the value of a bound entry textbox:

```
<ContentView Grid.Row="2"  Margin="30,0,30,0" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="1">
                        <Entry 
                            x:Name="txtLastName" 
                        Text="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.ContactDetails.LastName}" 
                        Placeholder="Last Name" PlaceholderColor="#cccccc" HeightRequest="40" 
                        TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium"
                        VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                    </ContentView>
```

Is there a way to make the value within the Entry accessible via code behind (say through a button click), if I wanted to perform an action (such as setting the value within to empty)

```
  private void ClearTextBoxesButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            //Clear value
            this.FindByName<Entry>("txtLastName").Text = string.Empty;

}
```

Doing the above results in null value of the textbox, which isn't populated even though the field is populated in the form. It seems as if it cannot find the textbox.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: if you are using binding, then you clear the textbox by clearing the property its bound to

Comment: As stated Jason, you can just set the value of ContactDetails.LastName to a string.Empty or to null, this will reset the value of the bound text property of your Entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Jason's reply, the entry text bind BindingContext.ContactDetails.LastName, if you want to clear Entry Text value, you just need to clear ContactDetails.LastName.

Note:please don't forget to implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface for ContactDetails class.

Please take a look the following code:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="template">
        <ContentView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Entry
                    x:Name="txtLastName"
                    FontSize="Medium"
                    HeightRequest="40"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Placeholder="Last Name"
                    PlaceholderColor="#cccccc"
                    Text="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.contact.LastName}"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    VerticalOptions="End" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentView>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ContentView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource template}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Clicked="btn1_Clicked"
            Text="btn1" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage.Content>

  public partial class Page18 : ContentPage
{
    public ContactDetails contact { get; set; }
    public Page18()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        contact = new ContactDetails();

        contact.LastName = "cherry bu";
        this.BindingContext = this;

    }

    private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        contact.LastName = "";
    }
}

public class ContactDetails:ViewModelBase
{
    private string _LastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _LastName; }
        set
        {
            _LastName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }

}
```

The ViewModelBase is the class that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged

```
 public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```